# Error loading page on clicking an anchor tag in android phonegap app in ice cream sandwhich

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

i am developing an **android phonegap** app using **phonegap 1.3** and **jquery mobile 1.0** My app works perfectly fine in all android versions before 4.0.0

But in 4.0.0 and above im facing an issue. I have an anchor which when users click, takes the to another 'page'.

```
<div class="ui-input-share  ui-btn-corner-all ui-body-c" id="mk_home">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="ui-input-text"  data-role="none"  >Whats up?</a>
</div>
```

In the emulator having android 4.0.3, when i click on this i get an error saying **"Error loading page"** When i check the logs in logcat, i see an error saying

```
Unknown chromium error: -6
```

any idea as to what can i do to get it working?

Comment: do you have the jquery mobile images embedded in your project ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error was coming because webkit in ics is broken in handling

```
?param=abc
```

with urls. So if u have a url like

```
domain.com?p1=a
```

which u hit, then you would get such an error. The best fix for now would be to test your webapp in browser and see when and where you add params to the url and remove those.

You can in place save those params  in localstorage and retrieve when needed.

Comment: This is amazing!!! I built my whole app using hashes and searches... this is a huge problem!!!!

Comment: I couldn't believe it at first, but this is really the problem! must deploy to device to really test it...

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using jQuery I would recommend to use `jQuery` to wire up your events as well. With that being said using `e.preventDefault()`; and `e.stopImmediatePropagation();` should stop `jQuery` mobile from performing the default action on the .

```
$("#verify").click(function (e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    //Do important stuff....
});
```

**Update**

The better way to use your existing markup would be to simply add rel="external" to your  And your onclick should behave correctly.

```
<p>
  <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="a" onclick="doSomething(); return false" rel="external">VERIFY</a>
</p>
```

This will work since jQuery Mobile will treat the link as a normal  tag and return false will simply stop the default action.

Comment: i am doing a $(id).unbind(event,eventFn).bind(event,data,eventFn) for the anchor.   will try rel=external.

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery Mobile, when you want to use `<a href=...> </a>`, you'd better use  **rel="external"** in `<a>` , in order to jump to target page correctly.
If you want to use JavaScript, you'd better not to use in `<a href='...'>`, because href is hash allocation but not JavaScript code attribute.

jQuery Mobile do not support anchor. If you need to use anchor, you have to do some trade-off. You can reference this link, [jQuery Mobile Anchor Linking](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-mobile-anchor-linking)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the jquery itself adds those url params in ajax requests. This is the case when you activated caching.
You could easily disable this feature for the whole project using:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
```

Hope this helps somebody.